# If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement Vue3 composite api

Tags: vuejs3

[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: component
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via
compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

[image]

my component NavbarLink

```
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
    hrefLink: { type: String, required: true, default: "#" },
});
</script>

<template>
    <component>
        <a class="hover:text-gray-400" :href="hrefLink"><slot /></a>
    </component>
</template>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix the error, replace the `<component>` tag with the actual component name. To use HTML tags without needing to include other Vue components, use the `<div>` tag or other HTML tags. Here's an example of improving your code by using the  tag:

```
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
    hrefLink: { type: String, required: true, default: "#" },
});
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <a class="hover:text-gray-400" :href="hrefLink"><slot /></a>
    </div>
</template>
```